# django Как из одной таблицы взять данные и передать в другую таблицу?

Tags: python, django

Только только начал изучать Python&Django и возник вопрос. Есть таблица trmx с столбцами name и quantity. Есть таблица trsx_q с столбцами name , quantity ,city . Мне надо при нажатие кнопки "send" данные с таблицы trmx сохранились в таблице trsx_q. Но чтоб я мог менять только столбец quantity. После этого в таблице trmx уменьшились quantity . Например таблица trmx с данными name:товар1 quantity:140. Нажимаю кнопку "send" открывается окно меняю только столбец quantity  например:10 и добавляю city:Москва он сохраняется в таблице trsx_q. В таблице trmx name:товар1 quantity:130(данные уменьшился).Надеюсь нормально объяснил .Можно такое реализовать?

```
def trmxviews(reguest): 
    trmx = trmx.objects.all() 
    return render(reguest, 'main/maintr.html', {'trmx ': trmx}) 
    
def trsx_qviews(reguest): 
    trsx_q = trsx_q.objects.all() 
    return render(reguest, 'main/trsqviews.html', {'trsx_q ': trsx_q})
```

```
class trmx(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Названия')
    quantity = models.IntegerField('Количество')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Товар_общая'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товар_общая'

class trsx_q(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Названия')
    quantity = models.IntegerField('Количество')
    city = models.CharField('Город')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Город_распределения'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Город_распределения'
```

создал класс для модели trmx

```
class trxmdetail(DetailView):
    model = trmx
    template_name = 'main/trxdetail.html'
    context_object_name = 'protrx'
```

создал форму для trsx_q

```
class trsx_qForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = trsx_q
        fields = ['name', 'quantity', 'city']

        widgets ={
            "name": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Название',
            }),
            "quantity": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Количеств',
            }),
            "city": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Город',
            }),
        }
```

функция для сохранения данных в таблице trsx_q

```
def createtrsx_q(reguest):
    error = ''
    if reguest.method == 'POST':
        form = trsx_qForm(reguest.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/main/home')
        else:
            error = 'Форма неправильно заполнено'

    form = trsx_qForm()

    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error
    }

    return render(reguest, 'main/createtrx_q.html', data)
```

И функция для сохранение данных в табл данных trsx_q

```
class trxm_tupdate(UpdateView):
    model = trmx
    template_name = 'main/createtrx_q.html'
    form_class = trsx_qForm
```

#createtrx_q

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="features">
        <h1 style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">Добавления</h1>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.id }}
            <span style="font-size: 2px; background: red;">{{ form.name }}</span>
            {{ form.quantity }}
            {{ form.city }}
            <span style="font-size: 20px;">{{ error }}</span>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Добавить запись</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Последняя функция не правильно работает. Он берет данные с таблицы trmx и открывается форма для таблицы trsx_q , но самом таблице trsx_q данные не сохраняет а обновляет таблицу trmx. Подскажите как исправить

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Чтобы улучшить ответ, нажмите кнопку "Править" под вопросом и добавьте дополнительную информацию. В этот раз я добавил ваш код, но на будущее - делайте это сами

Comment: И раз работа с моделями - приложите код этих моделей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишите класс формы для работы с моделями [Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/), [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)

В методе `save()` формы укажите необходимую вам логику.

Поиск по объектам - `<Model>.objects.filter(name="<value>")`

Этого достаточно, чтобы решить вашу задачу.

А если подробнее:

- создайте `view` для этого действия
- создайте форму, выводите ее на странице
- в форме укажите `action="..."` на `view` с обработкой формы. Если совпадает с текущей страницей, можете оставить пустым
- в `save` формы ваша логика
- всё

Comment: изменил код и добавил функцию и форму . Но не сохраняет

Comment: не определили метод `save`, где должна быть ваша логика вычитания данных из объекта модели